# How to share the objects between two JVM processes

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I am writing a chat room application with a given client.jar. My main job is to write the server. Then I can run the server.jar in command window, if i want to set up the second server, I will open another command window and run the server.jar again. Here is my brief code:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*Read the parameter,such as IP address and port from config file
         Each line in the file represents a server*/

        // Code: Get the parameter for setting serverSocket...

        /*Here I want to use a ServerInfo class to store 
         name of all the activated server, it has an attribute 
         'ArrayList<String> list', every time before set
         up the server, firstly add server name to the list*/

        ServerInfo.getInstance().list.add(server name);

        try {
            // set up the serversocket
            while(true) {
                // listening to the client
            }
        } catch {
            // other codes
        }
    }
}
```

For the `ServerInfo` class, I use the singleton to get its instance, so that every time I can add the server name to the same `ArrayList`

Here comes the question. After I run the server.jar first time, I can successfully add a name to the list, however, when i run the server.jar again to setup another server, the method `getInstance()` doesn't work, it seems like a new instance of `ServerInfo` class is created and the second server name is added to the `Arraylist` of this new instance. So I can't add all the names into the `ArrayList` of same instance.

Anyways to handle this issue?

Comment: concurrency, semaphore, syncronize... those are tags for your seach

Comment: You start another JVM process and you're surprised that the list isn't pre-populated with the object living in the first JVM process? Would that be a fair summary of your question?

Comment: "Anyways to handle this issue?" Just do what is requested: "/*Read the parameter,such as IP address and port from config file
             **Each line in the file represents a server** */" - You can do this in one single call of the program. Spoiler: Use loops.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, your summary is exactly right, sorry that I am new to java and cannot summary the question very well

Comment: Then the answer is obvious: threads all live within the _same_ JVM process. You can't run `server.jar` twice and share objects between them.

Comment: @Fildor Thx for you reply. Actually, when i run the server.jar through the command window, I will type the server name I want to activate. So the program will only match one line in the config file and setup the corresponding server. When i setup the second server, it will repeat the above operation

Comment: Ah, I see. So you actually want separate instances. In that case, you will probably have to do some Service discovery, so every Server in the same network knows of other Servers or share the information in a commonly accessible DB. Where using a common DB is probably easier to do.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, really? I always think there can be a solution for this issue and make a big effort...So if i want to run multiple servers, the way is to run they as threads within the same JVM process, then they can share the object, right? Or if I can only run server.jar server several times, are there any ways to share information between JVM processes, besides the object?

Comment: It's much harder to share between processes, they have to exchange messages and you need a complete technology stack for that. Using network sockets is a typical approach.

Comment: @Fildor Not exactly, I actually want to get the same instance. When I run the server.jar first time(first JVM process), it will recall the ServerInfo and create an instance, then put server name into it. When i run server.jar again(the second JVM process), I hope can get the instance reference which is created in the first JVM process, then can add second server name into its list, so in this way, no matter how many servers i create, they can share the instance and know what else server is setup. But unfortunately, as Marko said, it's not ok to share objects between JVM processes.

Comment: @ 刘世勋 : What protocol are you using for the chat application, and what is the format of the config file that you mention? If you are using UDP, you can set up each server both as an UDP Multicast server and client. If you run the server.jar, it would join a predefined multicast group and broadcast it's config data (i.e. server name, IP and whatever). All other chat servers that are already up and running would receive that data and can update their list of chat servers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are running server.jar twice. This creates two different java processes and **not threads**. Here, as there is no inter-process communication between the two processes (2 server.jar processes) the objects cannot be shared. They are treated as a separate one.

Sharing objects between two different server instances needs to be consider very carefully.

**For Example:** Let's Say you have 2 different servers to handle requests of your website and when a User log-in into your site you want to share the **Session object** among both the servers, So that if one server goes down another server can handle the ongoing request. Hence, the User would not get any internal server exception.

This scenario can be implemented by using some Application Servers like **JBoss AS in managed domain mode.**

For more details on Jboss AS managed domain mode, please check this 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Operating+modes

Comment: `Sharing objects between two different server instances is a tough job.` I wouldn't say it's tough, but it needs due consideration.

Comment: yeah, I agree on this.

Comment: You are right about the two threads living in distinct processes. From there on, your answer won't help the questioner with his/her problem. This is obviously a beginners/intermediate programmers course assignment. Throwing in JBoss here is pure overkill for what is required to solve the problem.